# Indexing takes long time with for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am running this `for loop` without any problems but it takes a long time. I guess it can be faster with apply family but not sure how. Any hints?

```
set.seed(1)
nrows <- 1200
ncols <- 1000
outmat <- matrix(NA, nrows, ncols)
dat <- matrix(5, nrows, ncols)
 for (nc in 1 : ncols){
  for(nr in 1 : nrows){
    val <- dat[nr, nc]
    if(!is.na(val)){
      file <- readBin(dir2[val], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1200*1000)
      # my real data where dir2 is a list of files 
      # "dir2 <- list.files("/data/dir2", "*.dat", full.names = TRUE)"
      file <- matrix((data = file), ncol = 1000, nrow = 1200) #my real data

      outmat[nr, nc] <-  file[nr, nc]
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you describe your data a bit. Its not clear why you don't read all 1200 x 1000 as a single block into memory. How many of these blocks do you have?  I don't use bin files (tend to use csv files with `read.table` or `fread`) so may be missing the point.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have 1200000 different files or not, but your loop takes so long because you are actually reading 1200000 files, and disk access if very slow. You won't get much quicker using apply. If you don't have so many files, I would suggest reverting your process to first read each file and store its data, then loop over the data to process it as needed.

Comment: How many are the several files in `dir2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions.

The first fills more memory, but is more efficient and I guess feasible if you have 24 files, as you stated. You read all the files at once, then you subset properly according to `dat`. Something like:

```
allContents<-do.call(cbind,lapply(dir2,readBin,n=nrows*ncol,size=4,"numeric")
res<-matrix(allContents[cbind(1:length(dat),c(dat+1))],nrows,ncols)
```

The second one can handle a slightly bigger number of files (say 50-100). It reads chunks of each file and subset consequently. You have to open as many connections as the number of files you got. For instance:

```
outmat <- matrix(NA, nrows, ncols)
connections<-lapply(dir2,file,open="rb")
for (i in 1:ncols)  {
    values<-vapply(connections,readBin,what="numeric",n=nr,size=4,numeric(nr))
    outmat[,i]<-values[cbind(seq_len(nrows),dat[,i]+1)]
}
```

The `+1` after `dat` is due to the fact that, as you stated in the comments, the values in `dat` range from 0 to 23 and `R` indexing is 1-based.